# Will the checked items in a gridview be unchecked if AllowPaging is False?

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview with 13 pages with 5 item each. The first column is a checkbox, and I want to get all the checked items in all pages.

So I want to loop through the WHOLE GRIDVIEW and get all checked items. Is that possible? Or if I set the AllowPaging to false and rebind it, will all checked items be unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with paging or not, it doesn't matter cause when you bind the gridview again all the checks will be gone. what you need to do is set a global variable that will hold the value if all the checkboxes should be checked or not and on the gridview_rowdatabound event it will check the checkboxes again even if you enabled paging.